# Is there a 64-bit version of Google Chrome for Mavericks?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, 64-bit

Is there a 64-bit version of Google Chrome for OS X Mavericks?

I need to run NetBeans and it requires Java 7 Update 10 at least.

Comment: what does netbeans have to do with chrome?

Comment: it requires java 7 update 10 at least... and I want google chrome x64 at the same time.

Comment: netbeans is an ide for writing java, chrome is a browser, still don't see the relationship

Comment: @dstarh I presume they're referring to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/oOdGABuqmnk).

Comment: @grgarside yup that is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 9):

**Since v39, Chrome is 64-bit.**

<strike>At the time of writing, there is no 64-bit version of Google Chrome for Mac.</strike>

You should be able to run your Java content in Safari for now, since Safari is 64-bit and can run Java 7.

Comment: Im writing this from the year 2020, and still there is no Chrome 64bit for Mac. Why? Because Google doesn't care.

Comment: @thedp 64 bit Chrome for Windows was released yesterday; OS X should be coming soon

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep this thread up to date - Google Chrome is now 64-bit, since v39

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is officially no 64-bit version of Google Chrome for Mac, neither is there a 64-bit Chromium version for Mac.

You can however, download an experimental build of [64-bit Chromium for Mac](http://chromium.woolyss.com/#mac-64-bit).

Alternatively you can [download the source code](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) and [build your own version of 64-bit Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support) with the following command

```
build/gyp_chromium -Dtarget_arch=x64 -Dhost_arch=x64
```

---

## Development Status

The Chromium Development team has been working on building 64-bit Google Chrome since August 2009. Consider starring this Chromium bug/feature request and contributing if you are able to [Chromium Issue 18323](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18323&can=5&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)